# GRUB - automatically boot Ubuntu, or boot Windows when shift is held (WITHOUT showing the menu)?

Tags: boot, grub2

Before someone marks it as such, this question is *not* a duplicate: I'm not only asking how to automatically boot Ubuntu and show GRUB's menu when I hold shift during boot. I want to set up GRUB so that, when I hold shift, it boots Windows without displaying the menu.

I know it can be done: I've seen it on the PC of a friend of mine (albeit the other way around: his PC would automatically boot Windows, or boot Ubuntu if he held shift during boot), unfortunately that person is pretty tech illiterate and I don't want to chase down the person that set up his PC.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround i found for Asus laptops:

1. Edit GRUB's menu with GRUB2 Editor, GRUB Customizer, or even BURG so that Windows option no longer to appear in the list. This will make PC boots directly into Ubuntu.
2. When starting laptop, press `Esc` key **immediately** until the UEFI menu comes up and select your desired OS from there. Both Windows and Ubuntu should be available. UEFI menu doesn't splash up automatically on screen at boot time, so the Windows option will remain out of sight and no one will be the wiser.

I know it's not exactly automatic, but it's the closest thing to it that i know. My guess is the shift option you described was achieved by means of a grub editor.